# GOCI Radiance to Reflectance

Tags: reflectance

How can I convert a GOCI satellite image from Radiance to Reflectance?
I have been searching through the internet, but most of them are related to other satellites. I try to calculate the reflectance using the typical approach, yet again, I found that I cannot find proper value of ESUN.

Is there something obvious I have missed or misunderstanded?